# Delete environmental variable from docker image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, environment-variables

I have looked around online and tried the obvious route (explained below) to remove an environmental variable from a docker image.

1 - I create a container from a modified ubuntu image using:

`docker run -it --name my_container my_image`

2 - I inspect the image and see the two environmental variables that I want to remove using:

`docker inspect my_container`

which yields:

```
...
    "Env": [
        "env_variable_1=abcdef",
        "env_variable_2=ghijkl",
        "env_variable_3=mnopqr",
...
```

3 - I exec into the container and remove the environmental variables via:

```
docker exec -it my_container bash
unset env_variable_1
unset env_variable_2
```

4 - I check to make sure the specified variables are gone:

```
docker inspect my_container
```

which yields:

```
...
    "Env": [
        "env_variable_3=mnopqr",
...
```

5 - I then commit this modified container as an image via:

`docker commit my_container my_new_image`

6 - And check for the presence of the deleted environmental variables via:

```
docker run -it --name my_new_container my_new_image
docker inspect my_new_container
```

which yields (drumroll please):

```
...
    "Env": [
        "env_variable_1=abcdef",
        "env_variable_2=ghijkl",
        "env_variable_3=mnopqr",
...
```

AKA the deleted variables are not carried through from the modified container to the new image in the `docker commit`

What am I missing out on here? Is `unset` really deleting the variables? Should I use another method to remove these environmental variables or another/modified method to commit the container as an image?

PS: I've confirmed the variables first exist when inside the container via `env`. I then confirmed they were not active using the same method after using `unset my_variable`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to edit the Dockerfile that built the original image.  The [Dockerfile `ENV` directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) has a couple of different syntaxes to set variables but none to unset them.  [`docker run -e`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables) and the [Docker Compose `environment:` setting](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment) can't do this either.  This is not an especially common use case.

Depending on what you need, it may be enough to set the variables to an empty value, though this is technically different.

```sh
FROM my_image
ENV env_variable_1=""
RUN test -z "$env_variable_1" && echo variable 1 is empty
RUN echo variable 1 is ${env_variable_1:-empty}
RUN echo variable 1 is ${env_variable_1-unset}
# on first build will print out "empty", "empty", and nothing
```

The big hammer is to use an entrypoint script to unset the variable.  The script would look like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
unset env_variable_1 env_variable_2
exec "$@"
```

It would be paired with a Dockerfile like:

```sh
FROM my_image
COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["same", "as", "before"]
```

`docker inspect` would still show the variable as set (because it is in the container metadata) but something like `ps e` that shows the container process's actual environment will show it unset.

As a general rule you should always use the `docker build` system to create an image, and *never* use `docker commit`.  ("A modified Ubuntu image" isn't actually a reproducible recipe for debugging things or asking for help, or for rebuilding it when a critical security patch appears in six months.)  `docker inspect` isn't intrinsically harmful but has an awful lot of useless information; I rarely have reason to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try with this way, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39684436/3293508):

```
docker exec -it -e env_variable_1 my_container bash
```

And then commit the container as usual.

Comment: Careful: using -e variablename with no value can work, but only if the variable does not exist in the host environment where you are running the docker command. The docs state that it is intended to pass through a variable: "If the operator names an environment variable without specifying a value, then the current value of the named variable is propagated into the container’s environment".

Comment: For me, this approach did not work.  The approach creates a ```bash``` session that does not have the variable set.  However, when I later attached to the container without the ```-e``` parameter, the variable remained.

Answer (score 1):

I personally was looking to remove all environment variables to have a fresh image but without losing the contents inside the image.
The problem was that when i reused this image and reset those environment variables with new values, they were not changed, the old values were still present.

My solution was to reinitialize the image with `docker export` and then `docker import`.

**Export**
First, spin up a container with the image, then export the container to a tarball

```
docker export container_name > my_image.tar
```

**Import**
Import the tarball to a new image

```
docker import my_image.tar my_image_tag:latest
```

Doing this will reset the image, meaning only the contents of the container will remain.
All layers, environment variables, entrypoint, and command data will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a shell script ("proxy-capsule.sh), which I use in my Dockerfile. The script sets the HTTP proxy for the current bash session and executes the actual command afterwards:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail

export HTTP_PROXY="$1"
export HTTPS_PROXY="$1"
export NO_PROXY="$2"

export http_proxy="$1"
export https_proxy="$1"
export no_proxy="$2"

shift 2 # discard the first and second script argument

exec "$@" # use the remaining arguments to execute the actual command in the current environment
```

... and then in the Dockerfile ...

```
FROM postgres:14.6-alpine3.17

ARG HTTP_PROXY
ARG NO_PROXY

# Create app directory and upload proxy-capsule.sh script
RUN mkdir /app
COPY proxy-capsule.sh /app/proxy-capsule.sh

# Update package manager
RUN /app/proxy-capsule.sh $HTTP_PROXY $NO_PROXY apk update
```

This way, the http proxy is only set for the single bash session and you don't have to remove it on startup in the entrypoint script. In my opinion, this is the more accurate solution, since it results in a cleaner Docker image. If an http proxy is required in the container runtime environment, the environment variables can be specified using the `-e` argument of the `docker run` command.

The downside is, that you have to prefix all commands in your Dockerfile with `RUN /app/proxy-capsule.sh $HTTP_PROXY $NO_PROXY` which require access to the internet.